# Correct positioning for border

Tags: html, css

I want to style a warning message by adding a left border. I did this but there is a problem with the left border because it is not placed inside of the red border...it is displaced somehow to left

HTML:

```
<div class="msg-warning">Random warning message</div>
```

CSS:

```
.msg-warning {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border-left-width: 12px;
}

.msg-warning {
  border-left-color: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uoedzqj1/

Comment: your code is switching the left border color from `red` to `blue`. its not displacing it, its replacing altogether.

Comment: Add semicolons after your CSS. `border:1px solid lightGray;` https://jsfiddle.net/9nrzon87/

Comment: Sorry, edited the code

Comment: if you look closely, the blue border has different dimensions

Comment: @indubitablee I need the blue border to have uniform dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could trying like this:

```css
.msg-warning {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow:-12px 0 blue;
  margin-left:12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg-warning">Random warning message</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uoedzqj1/2/

Answer (score 0):

something like this? nest another `div` in your `.msg-warning` div

```css
.msg-warning {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0px 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.blue {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg-warning"><div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>Random warning message</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use outline and border properties:

```
 .msg-warning {
    outline: 1px solid lightGray;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    border-left:12px solid #FCF8E3;
  }
```